# How Can I edit my buttons

Tags: android

I tried to use a `LinearLayout` with 4 buttons but the last one was cut. How can I edit my code to get button's width corresponding to all smartphones'resolutions
[image]

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.2"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/red"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="RED" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/blue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="BLUE" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/yellow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="YELLOW" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/green"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="GREEN" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks

Comment: use android:layout_weight="1"

Answer (score 1):

make `width="0dp"` in all buttons and add

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

to all buttons

Answer (score 0):

Use `weightSum` to get this equally divided layout by adjusting `layout_weight`

Try this once:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="4"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/red"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="RED" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/blue"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="BLUE" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/yellow"
            android:layout_width=match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="YELLOW" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/green"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="GREEN" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

First,set `android:weightSum="4"` in the `LinearLayout`.

And set `android:layout_width="Odp"` and `android:layout_weight="1"` in your `Button` .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="4"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/red"
        android:layout_width="Odp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="RED" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/blue"
        android:layout_width="Odp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="BLUE" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/yellow"
        android:layout_width="Odp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="YELLOW" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/green"
        android:layout_width="Odp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="GREEN" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @Lara Fab ,you can check my answer .